# X System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (22):Invalid argument - Azure SQL Database - Upload data Error

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-studio

I am new Azure. I have created SQL Server & SQL database, trying to upload `.csv` file data to SQL database.

I am using `Azure Data Storage` to upload data.

I connected to Azure -> Import wizard -> chose file -> Preview Data -> Modify Columns -> Import.

I am getting below error.

[image]

**Tried** - set firewall server -> add client IP But no luck.

Can anyone help me to resolve this ?

Thanks,
Jay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually comes when data in `.csv` file doesn't match default data type assigned in Azure Data Studio.

Do not change the data types while you import the file.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks.